# Undefined symbols, using C++ in iOS

Tags: c++, ios

I'm getting an error which I cannot resolve.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:  
"ObjSurface::ObjSurface(std::string const&)", referenced from:
  -[RootViewController testObj] in RootViewController.o ld: 
       symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

ObjSurface.hpp

```
#include "Interfaces.hpp"

class ObjSurface : public ISurface {
public:
    ObjSurface(const string &name);
    int GetVertexCount() const;
    int GetLineIndexCount() const { return 0; }
    int GetTriangleIndexCount() const;
    void GenerateVertices(vector<float>& vertices, unsigned char flags) const;
    void GenerateLineIndices(vector<unsigned short>& indices) const {}
    void GenerateTriangleIndices(vector<unsigned short>& indices) const;
private:
    string m_name;
    vector<ivec3> m_faces;
    mutable size_t m_faceCount;
    mutable size_t m_vertexCount;
    static const int MaxLineSize = 128;
};
```

ObjSurface.cpp

```
ObjSurface::ObjSurface(const string &name) :
    m_name(name),
    m_faceCount(0),
    m_vertexCount(0)
{
    m_faces.resize(GetTriangleIndexCount() / 3);
    ifstream objFile(m_name.c_str());
    vector<ivec3>::iterator face = m_faces.begin();
    while (objFile) {
        char c = objFile.get();
        if (c == 'f') {
            assert(face != m_faces.end() && "parse error");
            objFile >> face->x >> face->y >> face->z;
            *face++ -= ivec3(1, 1, 1);
        }
        objFile.ignore(MaxLineSize, '\n');
    }
    assert(face == m_faces.end() && "parse error");
}
```

Useage in ViewController.mm:

```
#include "ObjSurface.hpp"
    surfaces[0] = new ObjSurface(path + "/Ninja.obj");
```

My build settings:

[image]

Do I have to define some kind of namespace in my iOS class (std)?

Comment: Where's your implementation of the constructor?

Comment: Why are you compiling for x86?

Comment: @Mat, sorry it has now been added.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, does that cause any conflicts? I have not really considered it as an issue.

Comment: Is `ObjSurface.cpp` actually being compiled and linked? i.e. it it in the "Compile sources" build phase?

Comment: @Potatoswatter - there is an x86 implementation of iOS, sort of. It's the simulator. He's probably compiling for that.

Comment: @mattjgalloway, i am compiling for the simulator, so that makes sense! Thanks for the explaination..

Comment: @mattjgalloway, create an answer that i can accept. Thanks.

Comment: @JavaCake - Done. I assume it was that you didn't have it in the compile sources build phase then yeh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ObjSurface.cpp actually being compiled and linked? i.e. it it in the "Compile sources" build phase? It sounds like it isn't.

Comment: That error is at the link stage, so it's not specific to a single `hpp`, `cpp`, `mm`, etc file. But if you don't have an implementation of a function, then of course you'll get that error. Is that it?